# how to prevent a deadlock when you need to lock multiple objects

Tags: c#

Image this code:

You have 2 arrays, and you need to lock both of them in same moment (for any reason - you just need to keep locked both of them because they are somehow depending on each other) - you could nest the lock

```
lock (array1)
{
    lock (array2)
    {
        ... do your code
    }
}
```

but this may result in a deadlock in case that someone in other part of your code would do

```
lock (array2)
{
    lock (array1)
    {
        ... do your code
    }
}
```

and array 1 was locked - execution context switched - then array 2 was locked by second thread.

Is there a way to atomically lock them? such as

```
lock_array(array1, array2)
{
    ....
}
```

I know I could just create some extra "lock object" and lock that instead of both arrays everywhere in my code, but that just doesn't seem correct to me...

Comment: Creating an extra lock object *is* correct.

Comment: Using the single lock object that will lock both items is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

In general you should avoid locking on publicly accessible members (the arrays in your case). You'd rather have a `private static object` you'd lock on.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? I don't understand what you mean. What if that is something what needs to be publicly available, like some global array

Comment: The array can be public, that's not the problem. What you should be locking on should not be public. So in your class define a `private static object syncRoot = new object();` and then lock on it: `lock(syncRoot) { ... do something with the array ... }`.

Comment: ok - but what if I accessed this public array from some other object, which has no access to syncRoot - how would I lock it? How would I prevent the array from being modified while I am reading it?

Comment: @Petr Maybe make it a list instead, and overload the add/remove/clear etc methods where appropriate, and lock inside the overload when calling the `base` method (by the way, there's various synced collections in .net, in `System.Collections.Concurrent`)

Comment: Exactly as @DavidS. suggests.

Comment: @DavidS. but I am talking about hypothetical sample where I have 2 arrays which somehow depend on each other - by overriding add, remove of each of them, wouldn't guarantee to me that the other array would be locked in same time

Comment: @Petr If the syncroot object is static then that wouldn't be a problem. if not yes you'd have to find a way to use the same object as lock target.. I don't know if this is good practice; but maybe in your overridden collection's constructor you could have the syncroot object  as a parameter (enabling you to pass the same object for both lists).

Comment: @Silvermind but what if I need to write to it? I suppose what Darin is suggesting is to merge these 2 arrays (lists) into 1 big class that itself handle locks inside, using 3rd object (which is what I wanted to avoid), but probably is correct and only way to do this

Comment: @DavidS. ok then I didn't understand what you meant first time. So you mean override Add, Delete and issue lock to 3rd object, instead of list itself? That would work indeed, but that is what I thought that is not a correct way to do this (you need to create some extra object just to lock)

Comment: Don't make the locking object static unless the arrays are also static - otherwise you will pointlessly prevent simultaneous access to totally separate arrays. Pointless locking is bad. If the arrays are not static, make the locking object a nonstatic field. (I'm assuming the two arrays are both in the same class of course.)

Comment: @Petr yes.. I've always thought creating an object just to lock on is the correct/safest way.

Comment: @Petr, never change the lock anywhere, so never write to it. Declare it as `static readonly object myLockObject = new object();`

Answer (score 4):

You should never allow locking on publicly accessible variable as Darin said. For example

```
public class Foo
{
    public object Locker = new object();
}

public class Bar
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        lock(foo.Locker)
        {
            // doing something here
        }
    }
}
```

rather do something like this.

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<int> toBeProtected = new List<int>();
    private object locker = new object();

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        lock(locker)
        {
            toBeProtected.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for this is if you have multiple threads accessing multiple public synchronization constructs then run the very real possiblity of deadlock. Then you have to be very careful about how you code. If you are making your library available to others can you be sure that you can grab the lock? Perhaps someone using your library has also grabbed the lock and between the two of you have worked your way into a deadlock scenario. This is the reason Microsoft recommend not using SyncRoot.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by lock to arrays.
You can easily perform operation on both arrays in single lock.

```cs
static readonly object a = new object();
lock(a){
    //Perform operation on both arrays
    }
```